# Reduce size of image when converted to Base64

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, asp.net-web-api, cordova-plugins

I am using the File reader in JavaScript,i need to Post my image to WebApi and convert it into byte Array and save it in server,Its working fine,Now  my problem is base64 string increasing the size of image, Let say if i upload image of 30Kb, it is storing has 389Kb in server,How i can save in same size or reduce size of image need help

```
  //File Reader
function OnFileEditImageEntry(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    var ImageBase64 = evt.target.result;
    return ImageBase64 ;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }

 //WEB API//
public  IHttpActionResult UpdateUserDetails(ImageModel model)
 {

  try
    {
       if (model.ImageBase64 != "")
        {
          var PicDataUrl = "";
           string ftpurl = "ftp://xxx.xxxxx.xxxx/";
           var username = "xxx";
           var password = "xxxxx";
            string UploadDirectory = "xxxx/xx";
             string FileName =model.ImageFileName;
             String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", ftpurl, UploadDirectory,FileName);
                FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
                req.Proxy = null;
                req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                req.EnableSsl = false;
                req.UseBinary = true;
                req.UsePassive = true;
                byte[] data =Convert.FromBase64String(model.ImageBase64);
                req.ContentLength = data.Length;
                Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();
     }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you send it as raw bytes? Converting to Base64 definitely has some impact on the size and the performance. Depending on the actual data that you are sending applying gzip compression to those raw bytes could even further strip down the size. But given that you are uploading images they are already compressed (unless you are using a raw format) and gzip will not bring much benefit here.

Comment: i tried reader.readAsBinaryString(file); in file reader,its not give binary data,it give me some random string, so i cant convert it into byte array in webApi

Comment: Different formats will have different sizes, so unless you convert it back to the original format then you have to expect this.  A common approach for images is to save the image (as an image, not a base64 string) in a folder and then just store the filename in the database.  There are pros and cons for all ways of handling uploaded images, but for me this is the clearest way of doing it (plus it reduces page load time if you ever want to display the images on a website).

Comment: i am using Cordova Camera  Api for choosing the pics from gallery on success of that function i am calling file reader

Answer (score 0):

Send the raw binary instead of increasing the size ~30% with base64/FileReader

## with fetch

```
// sends the raw binary
fetch('http://example.com/upload', {method: 'post', body: file})

// Append the blob/file to a FormData and send it
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append('file', file, file.name)

fetch('http://example.com/upload', {method: 'post', body: fd})
```

## With XHR

```
// xhr = new ...
// xhr.open(...)

xhr.send(file) // or
xhr.send(fd) // send the FormData
```

---

Normally when uploading files, try to avoid sending a json as many developers tends to to wrong. Binary data in json is equal to bad practice (and larger size) eg:

```
$.post(url, {
  name: '',
  data: base64
})
```

Use the FormData#append as much as possible or if you feel like it:

```
fd.append('json', json)
```